# Difference between failed and canceled task

Tags: functions, conventions, failure

In case we hav functions `(f_1,....,f_n)` which runs in this order somewhere in the future.

I would like to define a relationship between those functions such that if `f_i` failed due to expection then `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` shouldn't run also.
Also, the user can cancel `f_i`. If he does, then `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` shouldn't run also.

I'm trying to determine the status (failed/canceled/something else) of `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` incase:

- `f_i` failed due to exception.
- `f_i` canceled by the user.

Is there any convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct state of the `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` would be "cancelled".

If `f_i` failed, you are cancelling `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` and not failing them. A failure is from an issue internally in the function, not external.

If `f_i` was cancelled, you are cancelling `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` and `f_i` as a set. Therefore they are all cancelled together.

Comment: Thanks I wanted to be sure with my assumption: `A failure is from an issue internally in the function, not external` =)

Comment: An argument could be made that the states of `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` are still "pending".  If the workflow ever allows f_i to rerun, then they can proceed.  Depends if the user is just cancelling f_i, or the whole workflow.

Comment: @user949300 If you have additional thoughts, please write an answer. I will love to read it!

Comment: "if `f_i` failed due to expection then `f_i+1,f_i+2,...f_n` shouldn't run also". The whole workflow is cancelled.